# Flask, проблемы с запуском сервера

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

Создал виртуальное окружение, подтянул вся зависимости из requirements.txt, все должно быть хорошо. Но после команды: `python manage.py runserver` получаю ошибку. Смысл её вроде как понял, но где именно список заменить на кортеж не пойму.

```
 * Restarting with stat
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 82, in <module>
    manager.run()

  File "/home/nomatterhowyoutry/Documents/Website-Flask/website-flask/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask_script/__init__.py", line 412, in run
    result = self.handle(sys.argv[0], sys.argv[1:])

  File "/home/nomatterhowyoutry/Documents/Website-Flask/website-flask/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask_script/__init__.py", line 383, in handle
    res = handle(*args, **config)

  File "/home/nomatterhowyoutry/Documents/Website-Flask/website-flask/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask_script/commands.py", line 425, in __call__
    **self.server_options)

  File "/home/nomatterhowyoutry/Documents/Website-Flask/website-flask/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 841, in run
    run_simple(host, port, self, **options)

  File "/home/nomatterhowyoutry/Documents/Website-Flask/website-flask/lib/python3.5/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 706, in run_simple
    reloader_type)

  File "/home/nomatterhowyoutry/Documents/Website-Flask/website-flask/lib/python3.5/site-packages/werkzeug/_reloader.py", line 265, in run_with_reloader
    sys.exit(reloader.restart_with_reloader())

  File "/home/nomatterhowyoutry/Documents/Website-Flask/website-flask/lib/python3.5/site-packages/werkzeug/_reloader.py", line 124, in restart_with_reloader
    close_fds=False)

  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 247, in call
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as p:

  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 676, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)

  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 1221, in _execute_child
    restore_signals, start_new_session, preexec_fn)

TypeError: <flask_script.commands.Server object at 0x7f69bd09f5c0>: fork_exec() argument 4 must be tuple, not list
```

Comment: Добавьте код вашего `manage.py` и ваши конфиги.